# Sort list python3

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting

I would like to order this list.

From:

```
01104D-BB'42
01104D-BB42
01104D-BB43
01104D-CC'42
01104D-CC'72
01104D-CC32
01104D-CC42
01104D-CC62
01104D-CC72
01104D-DD'74
01104D-DD'75
01104D-DD'76
01104D-DD'77
01104D-DD'78
01104D-DD75
01104D-DD76
01104D-DD77
01104D-DD78
01104D-EE'102
01104D-EE'12
01104D-EE'2
01104D-EE'32
01104D-EE'42
01104D-EE'52
01104D-EE'53
01104D-EE'72
01104D-EE'82
01104D-EE'92
01104D-EE102
01104D-EE12
01104D-EE2
01104D-EE3
01104D-EE32
01104D-EE42
01104D-EE52
01104D-EE62
01104D-EE72
01104D-EE82
01104D-EE83
01104D-EE92
01104D-EE93
```

To:

```
01104D-BB42
01104D-BB43
01104D-BB'42
01104D-CC32
01104D-CC42
01104D-CC62
01104D-CC72
01104D-CC'42
01104D-CC'72
01104D-DD75
01104D-DD76
01104D-DD77
01104D-DD78
01104D-DD'74
01104D-DD'75
01104D-DD'76
01104D-DD'77
01104D-DD'78
01104D-EE102
01104D-EE12
01104D-EE2
01104D-EE3
01104D-EE32
01104D-EE42
01104D-EE52
01104D-EE62
01104D-EE72
01104D-EE82
01104D-EE83
01104D-EE92
01104D-EE93
01104D-EE'102
01104D-EE'12
01104D-EE'2
01104D-EE'32
01104D-EE'42
01104D-EE'52
01104D-EE'53
01104D-EE'72
01104D-EE'82
01104D-EE'92
```

Can you help me?
thanks

Comment: What... have you tried to do this? Are there any special semantics to the sort, or is it just a normal A-Z search? Help us to help you.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply
I tried to do this                                                                                                                    with open("file.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()
    x = list(data)
    y = x.sort()
    print(y)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here, because you haven't explained how you want the sort to be done. But it *looks* like you want the character `'` to sort *after* the digits `0`-`9`, and the ascii sort order puts it *before* the digits. If that is correct, then you need to substitute a different character for `'`. A good choice might be `~` because it is the last printable ascii character.

If your data is in `mylist`, then

```
mylist.sort(key=lambda a: a.replace("'","~"))
```

will sort it in the order I'm guessing you want.

Comment: the script is not working:
with open("2.txt") as f:
 data = f.read()
 h = list(data.split("\n"))
 z = h.sort()
 print(z)

Comment: I thought you were having trouble with the *sort*. Please your code to the question and also the complete stack trace. "Not working" isn't enough to go on.